# Do directives that share a required ^parent share parent's $scope?

Tags: angularjs, scope, require, directive

I'm having an issue where I'm using require in both

`myDirectiveChild1` -- C1
`myDirectiveChild2` -- C1

The children's directive `require: ^myDirectiveParent` -- P

P defines `$scope.myVar`

but C1 and C2 seem to be over-writing the value of parent P's `$scope.myVar`

instead of each having their own copy.

Is that normal?

How can I get C1,C2 to have their own values?

Comment: show *some* code. `require` and `$scope` are different things

Comment: I'm saying in child directives 1 and 2, doing require: ^myParent, made child 1 and 2 have the same copy of myParent's scope.whateverVars. Is that normal? How can this behavior be changed?

Comment: `require` gives you the reference to the parent directive's controller. The scope is anyway available to all descendants, whether you use `requre` or not. I'm not sure what you mean by "can this behavior be changed". Which exact behavior? And what do you want to change it to? And why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a directive, you can define whether a directive creates a child scope `scope: true`, creates an isolate scope: `scope: { }`, or just uses the same outer scope (default): `scope: false`.

When your directive defines values on the scope, the default option is almost always the wrong one, because you can inadvertently overwrite the outer scope's property (or, if you intend to overwrite it, then you directive would be tightly coupled with that scope).

Your directives `c1` and `c2` seem to have `scope: false`. Instead, consider creating a child scope for both of them.

```
.directive("c1", function(){
  return {
    scope: true, // creates a child scope for c1
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.myVar = "foo"; // will not overwrite the parent's myVar
    }
  }
});
```

And so, each one would shadow the parent's `myVar` with their own:

```
<parent>
   <c1></c1>
   <c2></c2>
</parent>
```

Note that putting the two child directives on the same element will make them share a scope and one would overwrite the other:

```
<div c1 c2></div>
```

Note also, that `require` property only gives you a reference to the parent's controller. So, the parent can define an API through which those directives that `require` it can invoke actions. This has nothing to do with scope and scope inheritance.

Read more about creating directives in [Angular's directive guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), where concepts like these are described in more detail.

Comment: I wanted shared logic in parent P to control the setting of C1 and C2's myVar copies. How about that? How would I do that when using require or other inheritance structures?

Comment: `require` gives you the reference to the controller. You can define a function on the controller to provide the common logic. In any case, this seems like a different question

Comment: Oic. What might I use to reuse/extend/inherit logic+data in components? Ie, say P deals with pets, whereas C1 is for cats, and C2 for dogs. Say  there are many functions in P that could work for both C1 and C2, on vars that exist in both C1/C2. In many cases I can pass these into P from C's function. But in a lot of event-driven handler code, I can't pass args because I'm not the caller. In these cases, in OOP I'd think of P as holding a copy of each C's vars. Is this a design you don't/recommend in AngularJS, and how might I use it?

Comment: @mylord, you should a separate question and clarify your use case